# Google Compute Engine plugin issue

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform, cloud, jenkins-plugins, credentials

i'm trying to use Google Compute Engine plugin in jenkins and authentication and validate my jenkins credentials,  when configure the instance detail in compute engine plugin getting this error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVnjD.png)

Comment: 1) Did you configure the service account credentials in the screenshot? 2) What permissions (roles) does the service account have? Edit your question with details.

Comment: configure service account credential in json file and gave the role of service account, compute service admin v1,  compute network admin, compute security admin, editor, service account editor, service account user, storage admin.